# Can instance pool Id and driver instance pool Id can be same?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I was creating Databricks job with API. Just want to know if instance pool Id and driver instance pool Id can be same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's ok to use the same Instance Pool for both worker & driver nodes.  And really, if you don't specify a separate pool for driver, then the worker's instance pool will be used if it's configured.  This is described in the [documentation for clusters](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters.html#create), in the description of `instance_pool_id` setting:

> The optional ID of the instance pool to use for cluster nodes. If driver_instance_pool_id is present, instance_pool_id is used for worker nodes only. Otherwise, it is used for both the driver and worker nodes.